When refreshing a datasource in lookerstudio, why do I see that the same fields appear as missing, and added? If I accept that, the report gets broken
I'm trying to refresh my datasources in lookerstudio (using google sheets as a datasource) and they show all of them as missing fields and added fields. If I accept that, the report gets broken
enter image description here
I tried other sheets but it's happening with all of them.
I'd expect the lookerstudio to automatically recognize that they're the same fields so they don't get deleted and added because it gets the report broken

Same thing happening to me! We had to redo all the datasources from scratch and then when reconnecting it did work. But with old data sources it is not working for some reason...
